Flutter Rive Simple Animation autoPlay false
I am trying to build a simple animation that plays when i press a play/pause button but it seems to automatically play when the animation loads in.
Here is the code I use to build the controller affiliated with my simple animation:
controllers.add(SimpleAnimation(dacHeader['runList'][i]['animation'][0],
  autoplay: false));

This is where I call my SimpleAnimation to be built on screen:
Visibility(
  visible: widget.visibilityStates[index],
  child: SizedBox(
    width: widget.dacHeader['bgWidth'],
    height: widget.dacHeader['bgHeight'],
    child: RiveAnimation.file(
      '${widget.dir.path}/${widget.dacHeader['file']}',
      artboard: widget.dacHeader['runList'][index]
          ['artboard'],
      animations: widget.dacHeader['runList'][index]
          ['animation'],
      controllers: [widget.controllers[index]],
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    ),
  ),
),

Lastly, this is where I call the animation to play/pause:
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (isPlaying == false) {
      isPlaying = true;
      playRunList();
    } else {
      togglePlayStop();
    }
  },
  icon: Icon(
    isPlaying ? Icons.stop_circle : Icons.play_circle,
    weight: 200,
    fill: 0,
  ),
),
void playRunList() async {
  widget.controllers[0].reset();
  while (isPlaying == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.dacHeader['runList'].length; i++) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          widget.instructionText =
              widget.dacHeader['runList'][i]['instructionText'];
          widget.visibilityStates[i] = true;
          widget.controllers[i].isActive = true;
        });
      }
      await Future.delayed(
          Duration(milliseconds: widget.dacHeader['runList'][i]['dTime']),
          () {
        widget.visibilityStates[i] = false;
        widget.controllers[i].isActive = false;
        widget.controllers[i].reset();
      });

      if (isPlaying == false) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

